# Setting up context java:comp/env in Jetty running inside GWT 2.7

Tags: gwt, jetty, jndi

Contents of jetty-web.xml  in /WEB-INF:

```xml
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">  
  <Array id="plusConfig" type="java.lang.String">
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item> <!-- add for jndi -->
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>    <!-- add for jndi -->
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
  </Array>
  <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty">
    <Arg>java.naming.factory.initial</Arg>
    <Arg><Property name="java.naming.factory.initial" default="org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.InitialContextFactory"/></Arg>
  </Call>
  <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty">
    <Arg>java.naming.factory.url.pkgs</Arg>
    <Arg><Property name="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs" default="org.eclipse.jetty.jndi"/></Arg>
  </Call> 
</Configure>
```

Contents of jetty-plus.xml  in /WEB-INF:

```xml
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<!-- Add plus Configuring classes to all webapps for this Server -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration$ClassList" name="setServerDefault">
    <Arg><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Call name="addAfter">
      <Arg name="afterClass">org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Arg>
      <Arg>
        <Array type="String">
        <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
        <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Call>
</Configure>
```

This is my calling code in Servlet's init() method:

```java
Context _initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context _envCtx  = (Context) _initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

Error it throws:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env'
at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:449)
at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536)
at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:551)
at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:117)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
```

I'm running vanilla GWT 2.7 and I'm trying to use JNDI lookup in my server code.
I have also attached jetty-all-8.1.9.v20130131.jar and jetty-plus-8.1.9.v20130131.jar to the project since some of Context and JNDI classes are missing in GWT jars.  I tried to verify the version of jetty in GWT, and I got this:

```java
Server server = new Server(7070);
System.out.println(server.getVersion());

8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
```

I saw solution where you can configure JNDI other ways, however since I'm running in GWT, I can only work with the jetty-web.xml and jetty-plus.xml files.

When debugging the servlet, I'm getting context for:

```java
Context _envCtx  = (Context) _initCtx.lookup("java:comp");
```

But not for:

```java
Context _envCtx  = (Context) _initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

Stacktrace is above.

I'm really stuck here.  Any jetty gurus out there?

---

### Edit 1:

Added jetty-env.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure id='portal' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New id="DStest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
  <Arg></Arg>
  <Arg>jdbc/DSTest</Arg>
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver">
      <Set name="Url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost</Set>
      <Set name="User">sa</Set>
      <Set name="Password"></Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
</Configure>
```

And this to my web.xml:

```xml
<resource-ref>
  <description>Primary database</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/DSTest</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Still _envCtx is null with the exception below.  _initCtx.lookup("java:comp") does return org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext instance.

```java
Context           _initCtx          = new InitialContext();
Context           _envCtx           = (Context) _initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

results in

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env'
```

---

### Edit 2:

I must be missing something else (basic)....??!?
I changed that 1 line in jetty-env.xml to:

```
<Arg><Ref refid="portal"/>jdbc/DSTest</Arg>
```

And the doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
```

I could not find more appropriate .dtd  for v8.X
Still same problem.

Answer (score 6):

What's working for me (assuming you're not using SuperDevMode):

1. Add `-Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.InitialContextFactory` to the JVM parameters when you run DevMode. (in `extraJvmArgs` for gwt-maven-plugin)
2. Add dependencies for Jetty Plus and JNDI to your POM:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
       <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
       <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
       <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
       <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Have the JNDI entries configured in `jetty-web.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

       <New id="DataSource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
           <Arg>jdbc/XYZ</Arg>
           <Arg>
               <New class="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource">
                   <Set name="user">X</Set>
                   <Set name="password">Y</Set>
                   <Set name="databaseName">Z</Set>
                   <Set name="serverName">X</Set>
                   <Set name="portNumber">A</Set>
               </New>
           </Arg>
       </New>

       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry">
           <Arg>config/ABC</Arg>
           <Arg type="java.lang.String">Value</Arg>
       </New>
       <!-- ... -->
   </Configure>
   ```

That's it.

Comment: Hi, although this answer has not been accepted by the asker, I can confirm that it worked for me.  I am using GWT 2.6.0, which uses the same Jetty 8.1.12.v20130726.  However, I also needed to use a customized `c.g.g.d.s.j.JettyLauncher.java` with `bootStrapOnlyClassLoader()` returning `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` (detailed see this: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/8507)

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and the question).  I provided an answer with the details of my set up which I finally got it to work.  Comments are welcome! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47318195/1168041

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported usage, but it should work: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8526

You have to use the exact same version of Jetty dependencies though, and [GWT is using 8.1.12](https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tools/lib/jetty/)

Comment: I swapped out my 8.1.9  (!?@)  jars   for  8.1.12 :-).   And I modified the JettyLauncher as stated in the article, but with no additional success.

Answer (score 1):

[You need to have a `<resource-ref>` declared for this resource in your `WEB-INF/web.xml` too.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28055457/775715)

The thing is, the `java:comp/env` doesn't exist until:

- A reference is created (in either your webapp's specific `jetty-env.xml`, or in a top level server xml file)
- That reference is bound to the webapp instance (not the server instance).  See the first argument in your `org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource` declaration.
- Your webapp's `WEB-INF/web.xml` declares a `<resource-ref>` pointing to this Resource.

Jetty is just following the servlet spec here.

**Response to Edit #1**

[Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), upgrade to Jetty 9.

*These instructions are for Jetty 9.*

Two things ... (just like the link in the original answer above)

- Your `DOCTYPE` is wrong.  Update it.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
```

- You didn't bind your reference to your webapp, in fact, your XML snippet is configured to be bound to the JVM context.  (Argument #1 is unspecified/null)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure id="portal" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New id="DStest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg><Ref refid="portal"/></Arg> <!-- this is where the resource is bound -->
    <Arg>jdbc/DSTest</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver">
        <Set name="Url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost</Set>
        <Set name="User">sa</Set>
        <Set name="Password"></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints...  my comments are above in 'Edit 1'

Comment: Also, [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), upgrade to Jetty 9.

Comment: Thanks Joakim.  I made the changes (Edit #2) still same problem  .   Jetty 8 is shipped with GTW that is why i'm using it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question and the answer by Thomas.  I had a very similar situation.   It was very hard to get the right combination of configuration, but I finally got it to work.  I guess I may as well document my findings here.

I was doing this to set up `GWT 2.6`, which uses `Jetty 8.1.12v20130726`.  My
goal was to set up `JNDI` for a `DBCP2` connection pool.  I am running 
`GWT` in `Eclipse` in `DevMode`

**WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml**

I am using the `JVM` scope but set the values inside a `WebAppContext`

Note also that the name that is used is `java:comp/env/jdbc/datalakeDbcp2` (that is, with the prefix `java:comp/env/`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

    <New id="datalakeDsDbcp2" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg></Arg>                                 <!-- scope -->
        <Arg>java:comp/env/jdbc/datalakeDbcp2</Arg> <!-- name  -->
        <Arg>                                       <!-- value -->
            <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClassName">org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver</Set>
                <Set name="url">jdbc:hive2://someServer:somePort/someDb</Set>
                <Set name="username"></Set>
                <Set name="password"></Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>    

</Configure>
```

**JettyLauncher.java**

Copied a `JettyLauncher.java` from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/JettyLauncher.java) to your own working
directory (under the path of `src/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/` naturally)

There is only one local modification needed.

`bootStrapOnlyClassLoader`

```
/*
 * Change suggested by:
 * https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/SBFltI27ssk 
 */
private final ClassLoader bootStrapOnlyClassLoader 
    = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
//    private final ClassLoader bootStrapOnlyClassLoader = new ClassLoader(null) {
//    };
```

No need to change `WebAppClassLoaderExtension` -- just use it
as the original code:

```
private class WebAppClassLoaderExtension extends WebAppClassLoader {

  private static final String META_INF_SERVICES = "META-INF/services/";

  public WebAppClassLoaderExtension() throws IOException {
    super(bootStrapOnlyClassLoader, WebAppContextWithReload.this);
  }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**VM arguments (in `Eclipse`)**

```
-Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.InitialContextFactory
```

**WEB-INF/web.xml**

Perhaps because I am using the `VM` scope in my `jetty-web.xml`, I did
not need to change my `web.xml`

**Program code to obtain a JNDI named connection**

```
try {
   InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
   DataSource ds 
       = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/datalakeDbcp2");
   conn = ds.getConnection();
} catch (NamingException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
};
```

**References**

1. The code use `Jetty v8.1.12.v20130726` but I could not find the matching
   documentation, so I have been using the doc for 'Jetty 9.3.x'.  It
   seems still applicable:

   - [Chapter 12](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/using-jetty-jndi.html)
   - [Chapter 4](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-deployment.html)
   - [Chapter 3](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/quick-start-configure.html)
2. `GWT` Issue 8507 [here](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/8507)